# Why catch an Access Violation?

Tags: c++, error-handling, access-violation

Unlike C++ exceptions, an Access Violation indicates your applications runtime is compromised and the state of your application is, therefore, undefined. The best thing to do in that circumstance is to exit your application (generally done for you because it crashes).

I note that it is possible to catch one of these exceptions. In Microsoft Visual C++, for example, you can use `/EHa` or `__try/__catch` to do so.

So, what are the reasons you would want to catch them? As I understand it, there's no way for your application to recover.

Comment: You *could* be doing something generally unpleasant to the user at the time you crash. For example, you could have disabled their taskbar for whatever reason. You'll want to make sure that's reversed before you're done.

Comment: But if the runtime is compromised, what are the odds that continuing on to cleanup code will even work?

Comment: I suppose the worst that could happen would be that your application would crash. ;-)

Comment: Well hopefully one function call to the OS gets through and the user at least has a usable taskbar again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason might be to write a crash dump file; you would have more control over it and be able to write the exact type you wanted.  In Windows, for example, you could call [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do this.

Comment: This seems like the most likely thing a person would want to do given the circumstances. +1 for everybody else who gave a plausible answer, though. Also, a collegue directed me to a mirror of an article by Doug Harrison with some good info: http://www.360doc.com/content/11/0411/10/6287626_108773107.shtml

Answer (score 8):

You can recover from an access violation.

For example, you can create a dynamic array by allocating some address space with `VirtualAlloc`, but marking the memory it points at as not-present. Then, when you attempt to use some memory, you catch the access violation, map a page of memory where the access took place, then re-try the instruction that caused the violation.

Comment: Of course, when you do deep magic like that, you and all other involved parties have to know what they do. Otherwise, [bad stuff](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx) happens.

Answer (score 3):

Your app is not guaranteed to be stable after all access violations. But it can be stable or recover after some, so catching the access violation gives you the opportunity to:

1. Inform the user something went bad
2. Let the user attempt to save work
3. Attempt to recover
4. Log diagnostic information
5. Exit in the way you want, rather than disappearing.

A typical example of this is a host application that catches exceptions from a plugin. This way the host app (Photoshop, for example) can tell the user that "Plugin X crashed, and Photoshop is unstable... you should save your work, and restart Photoshop."

Note that this is different than C++ exception handling, which does not indicate unrecoverable errors at all, but is more of a stack unwinding feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to gracefully crash and let the user know what's going on, rather than just having the application disappear.

Answer (score 1):

If your application gets an access violation you may or may not be able to recover. If your application is left in an undefined state, you clobber your stack for instance, you're done.

Read from a runaway pointer probably won't corrupt your application and from that you likely can recover.

Either way, the fact that it is occurring indicates a bug in your code so instead of trying to recover you should catch the error and dump what state you can to help you debug the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately many of us write code that interacts with other platforms and the bugs are in other code.  It would be nice to isolate these and try to carry on if possible.